# Websphere Liberty seems to override System Property TransformerFactory set via jvm.options

Tags: xslt, websphere-liberty, jaxp

I am trying to migrate a legacy app that is using camel/cxf (offers some web services that include transformations) to Websphere Liberty 16.0.0.03 (IBM JRE 1.8). Tests are failing because the app uses extensions functions. I tried to disable secure processing as described [here](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_7.0.0/com.ibm.java.lnx.70.doc/user/limitations_7.html#limitations__xslterror).

This change has no effect. That's why I try to switch to Saxon Implementation globally by setting System Property "javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory=net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl" in jvm.options config file. Again - this does not work.

While debugging I can see, that com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.mbeans.PluginGenerator$2 is overriding the Property with  com.ibm.xtq.xslt.jaxp.compiler.TransformerFactoryImpl during Server start. I can see a method "PluginGenerator.revertTransformerFactoryIfNeccessary" in the stack that seems to trigger the change. Afterwards all FactoryFinder.find() will return the non-Saxon implementation.

Can anyone suggest how to either disable secure-processing successfully

or

a way to successfully set a custom TransformerFactory?

BTW: It seems to me like these 2 are bugs - do I report these as regular PMR?

### `EDIT: possible workaround`

As result of the helpful suggestions I added an '@WebListener' that will sets the System Property within the constructor (setting it in contextInitialized is too late as stylesheets seem to be compiled during application start and thus processing fails tests). I bundle this a "patch-jar" with the legacy app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Liberty web container plugin generator will only override the xml transformer factory if the IBM JDK is being used.

While the web container performs plugin generation using the IBM JDK, it will swap to an alternate transformer factory, and then reset to the IBM JDK default of which is `com.ibm.xtq.xslt.jaxp.compiler.TransformerFactoryImpl`.

I think it is worth opening a PMR here.  The `PluginGenerator` should not assume that it started with the default xml transformer factory, and should instead save off the value of `javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory` and then restore it after plugin generation has completed.

**Temp workaround:**
Since the `PluginGenerator` only swaps the XML transformer factory if you're running on the IBM JDK, you could change to an alternate JDK until your PMR gets resolved.

Comment: Hi Aguibert, thanks for your answer - is there a way to disable the PluginGenerator (as I don't need it for running in openshift)?

Comment: no, plugin generation cannot be disabled.  However, a new plugin-cfg.xml is only generated when the state of the web container changes (i.e. an app is added or removed, or server.xml config changes).  So if you don't trigger the plugin-cfg.xml generation, then you can get around this issue.  See: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/ae/rwlp_autogenerate_plugin_cfg_xml.html

Comment: Thank you for your help and useful suggestion!

Comment: A new-plugin-cfg.xml file is also generated during server start if there are applications present, so not triggering generation is not really possible.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that this is a bug. The official route for reporting problems is a PMR, but there is enough here for us to understand the problem and fix it through our beta program. If you want to get an iFix on a released version of the product (rather than waiting for it to come out via the beta program) then you will need to raise a PMR.